# How to do a continous 'wc -l' with gnu texttools?

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, logs, tail

I know of course that

```
cat logfile.txt | wc -l
120
```

will tell me the number of lines in a file.

Whereas

```
tail -f logfile.txt
```

will show me the new lines that another program writes to `logfile.txt`.

Is it possible to combine both so that I get a continuous updating line count of logfile.txt with standard text utilities?

I do know about

```
watch wc -l logfile.txt
```

but I do not want to re-count the whole file each time, that seems to be a waste. One would need an appended-only count every second or so and probably an `\r` instead of an `\n` at the end of line.

Comment: Is your file that big that recounting everything is a problem? In terms of waste: piping `cat` output to `wc` is also a big waste!!

Comment: Yes, it potentially is very big.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Maybe:

```
tail -n +1 -f file | awk '{printf "\r%lu", NR}'
```

Beware that it would output a number for every line of input (though overriding the previous value if sent to a  terminal).

Or you can implement the `tail -f` by hand in shell:

```
n=0
while :; do 
  n=$(($n + $(wc -l)))
  printf '\r%s' "$n"
  sleep 1
done < file
```

(note that it runs up to one `wc` and one `sleep` command per second which not all shells have built in. With `ksh93` while `sleep` is builtin, to get a built in `wc` (at least on Debian), you need to add `/opt/ast/bin` at the front of `$PATH` (regardless of whether  that directory exists or not) or use `command /opt/ast/bin/wc` (don't ask...)).

You could use `pv`, as in:

```
tail -n +1 -f file | pv -bl > /dev/null
```

But beware that it adds `k`, `M`... suffixes when the number is over 1000 (and [there doesn't seem to be a way around that](/q/183358)).

Comment: Whow to your `tail | awk` solution. Know your options: `-n +0` would not have occurred to me in this combination.

Comment: whoo! `pv` -- another useful new tool. thanks a bunch.

Comment: With grep you can add a filter to your stream: `tail -n +0 -f <my.log> | grep --line-buffered <mystring> | awk '{printf "\r%lu", NR}'`

Comment: @tombolinux, `awk` is a superset of `grep`. `tail -n +0 -f file | awk '/mystring/ {printf "\r%lu", ++n}'`

Comment: Cool. I add `END{print ""}` to make `awk` print a newline at the end.

Answer (score 7):

Try to count it with pure `bash` without `wc`:

```
a=0 ; tail -f file | while read -r line ; do ((a++)) ; echo $a ; done
```

or even like this to rewrite previous value:

```
a=0 ; tail -f file | while read -r line ; do ((a++)) ; echo -ne "\r$a" ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I don' believe there is anything like that. But it should be easy to whip up something along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$for_a_while = 1;

$oldcount = -1;
$count = 0;
open($fh, "<", $ARGV[0]);

for (;;) {
  for ($curpos = tell($fh); <$fh>; $curpos = tell($fh)) {
    $count++;
  }
  if($count != $oldcount) {
    print "$count\n";
    $oldcount = $count;
  }
  sleep($for_a_while);
  seek($fh, $curpos, 0);
}
```

(General idea cribbed from `perlfunc(1)`)

Comment: The number would increment every time  you do a `printf foo >> file`. You'd need to count the newline characters (like `wc -l` does in the shell solution I suggested), not the records returned by `<$fh>`. I don't think you need to use `tell` or `seek` at all.

Comment: The `<$fh>` reads a line by default, not records. The Perl manpage cited tells to do it this way for the sake of a possibly uncooperative environment (could depend on the filesystem, I guess NFS or other network-mounted filesystems might require a bit of prodding).

Comment: Try it for yourself, upon reaching end of file, `<$fh>` will return a record even if it's not terminated by a newline character. So if `perl` is sitting at the end of the file, and someone later does a `printf foo >> file`, then `<$fh>` will return `foo` (not a _line_ since it's not terminated by a newline character), and `$count` will be incremented  even though no extra line has been added to the file.

Comment: OP was supposed to monitor logfiles written a line at a time?

Comment: No, which is why your solution may not work. For instance, if the applications writing to the file buffers its output, then at any given time, the last line is likely not to be terminated so will be counted twice.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the awk-based solution: you might not need to see the counter ticking for each line in your log; it that's the case, you can have it like this (number would change for each 10 lines):

```
tail -n +0 logfile.txt | \
    awk 'a+=1{}a%10==0{printf "\r%lu", a}END{printf "\r%lu", a}'
```